# I have a bad text when i get html from url

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        URL url;

        try {
            // get URL content
            url = new URL("http://mp3.zing.vn/album/Chuyen-Tinh-Nha-Tho-Single-Van-Mai-Huong/ZWZAWZAZ.html");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            // open the stream and put it into BufferedReader
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                               new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;

            //save to this filename
            String fileName = "G:\\test1.txt";
            File file = new File(fileName);

            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            //use FileWriter to write file
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                bw.write(inputLine);
            }

            bw.close();
            br.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

This code when i run on netbean the text in `test1.txt` is ok. When I run it on eclipse 
the result :

```
�     
�{�ב'�w��*_��f���b��/�%uu����DY[��̪JvUf�2�̬p1�;�w��w�;�}}yV��`0$�}�'���sN>��/���^A��<�8q"�ĉ��뛻�����?�k{�ַ�Z"��<(ld2��M���ƶ�Kg�d~&����=�.g2�����B�u3���  ���j�k��:i�7���-��d�w��-�j���H�n�,ݤ/��o�}ku�7>}��o�y�?����;���}�x`;ݾuCKi����������w�|�t�'�Z�=h�|V뻞׷<�VF4H��X��Ô���>ZIl��o9~�y:��!~�$|�����2z�ȳ�{�۩jB�0��GX
```

Someone please help resolve this problem, thank !!!!

Comment: I have just tested with eclipse kepler(linux), and it work fine !

Comment: *`// TODO code application logic here`* - Tip: `// TODO remove this space wasting, redundant comment!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site you're retrieving is using an encoding that you're not handling properly. Looking at the site briefly shows that it's encoded using UTF-8, so you need to account for that while reading the data. `InputStreamReader` offers an option in its constructor for this.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                           new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF8"));
```

After some testing I've confirmed that **on my machine**, your code is actually working just fine as it is, since my default encoding is UTF-8 (and the system default charset gets used if you don't specify one). This may or may not be true for you; try printing out the encoding to see what you're reading:

```
System.out.println(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()).getEncoding());
// prints "UTF8" on my machine.
```

It's always **still best** to specify the charset, to make your code independent of the platform defaults.

If the above printout shows UTF8 or you still are seeing unexpected results once you've specified the charset, your problem is probably with the editor you're using to view the output file. Make sure your text editor can handle UTF8, and you should be good to go. I'm seeing this in SublimeText 3:

```
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head>              <title>Chuyện Tình Nhà Thơ (Single) - Văn Mai Hương | Album 320 lossless</title>        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
...
```

Comment: If you do not specify the charset, it uses the system default.  Your default may not be the same as that of the OP.  Failing to specify charset is almost always wrong.

Comment: @Aurand Absolutely true; I tried to make that more clear in my last edit.

Comment: @tan My last paragraph explains my best guess for if it still looks wrong--make sure you're using a good text editor that can handle the UTF-8 encoding. There are lots of free ones. Bear in mind that the *console* will probably show all kinds of garbage if you try to print out the results directly, rather than writing to a file.

Comment: @tan I think you open by NotePad, try to open by NotePad++

Comment: i try install MyLyn for eclipse and the text is good .Thank for your help .

Comment: @tan Glad to hear it! If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider voting it up and/or accepting it to indicate that it was helpful!

Comment: @Henry Keiter ,how can i do that ,i am newbie on this forum :D.

Comment: @tan Looks like you figured it out! :)